# What causes the error: "undefined reference to (function)" in a C library?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am building a library using Code::Blocks and I am testing to see if I can call it from my C program. However, when I compile the C program, I get the following error messages:

```
 AIA\Surse\tregpol.c|224|undefined reference to `test'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
```

Here are the contents of the files:

The main C program, **tregpol.c**:

```
#include "optim.h"
int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

The header file, **optim.h**:

```
#ifndef OPTIM_H_INCLUDED
#define OPTIM_H_INCLUDED

void test();

#endif // OPTIM_H_INCLUDED
```

The function source, **optim.c**:

```
#include "optim.h"

void test()
{
    printf("It works!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The `.dll`, `.a` and `.def` files are in the same folder as the above files.

Comment: You might not have added optim.c when compiling tregpol.c. If you're using gcc it would be something like `gcc optim.c tregpol.c`

Comment: Did you link your library?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with all command lines to build the library and to build the application. Just the sources are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to compile the "optim.c" and "main.c" file separately like this:

```
gcc -c optim.c && gcc -c main.c
```

That will produce 2 object files

And then linking them together:

```
gcc -Wall -O optim.o main.o -o main
```

Comment: The OP wants to build a library and link that. Your proposal just links two object files.